# date format excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, validation

Problem 1:
I have an Excel Cell which has the number format as dd.mm.yyyy.

I need to add limits to that particular cell, using Date criteria in Data Validation.
In the data validation I set the start date to be higher that 01-01-2012.

But, if I enter the date '01.02.2012' in the cell I get an error message. "You have type an invalid value".

How can I changes the date format in data validation to accept StartDate wiht the format 'dd.mm.yyyy'?

problem2:
When I set the date format in the cell to dd.mm.yyyy - it will convert all dates to this format except if i type eg. 2012.02.01 - it will still be displayed in this format!

Any help will be appreciated.

Note: This is not a programming question.

Answer (score 1):

Formatting normally only dictates how dates are displayed, not how your input is interpreted

Regional settings will determine how input is interpreted, what region are you in?

Presumably neither 01.02.2012 or 2012.02.01 are recognised as valid dates (at input). Try input as 01/02/2012 or 2012-02-01, you can still format the dates any way you want

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you could *define a custom format*!!

I did try and it worked!! :)